# Laravel previous and next page into controller

Tags: laravel, seo, canonical-link

I'm using this Laravel SEO package artesaos/seotools.

Is there a way for get prev and next page for pagination in controller?

```php
function seoMetaDetail($detail)
{
    SEOMeta::setCanonical(request()->fullUrl());         
    SEOMeta::setPrev(''); <-- previous page
    SEOMeta::setNext(''); <-- next page
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the current page from the query string.

```php
function seoMetaDetail($detail)
{
    $current = request()->query('page');

    SEOMeta::setCanonical(request()->fullUrl());
    // If there's no current, then we're on page 1. return null. Otherwise current - 1
    SEOMeta::setPrev($current ? ($current - 1) : null);
    // If there's no current, then we're on page 1, return 2. Otherwise current + 1
    SEOMeta::setNext($current ? ($current + 1) : 2);

}
```

You can also use the paginator methods.

```php
public function seoMetaDetail($detail)
{
    $paginator = YourModel::query()->....->paginate();

    SEOMeta::setCanonical(request()->fullUrl());
    SEOMeta::setPrev($paginator->previousPageUrl());
    SEOMeta::setNext($paginator->nextPageUrl());
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/pagination#paginator-instance-methods

Comment: works fine, I prefer second approach, only problem is for last page where I can't detected if exists or not. If my blog has 10 pages, on tithe page SetNext will get 'https://example.com/blog?page=11".

Comment: According to the documentation, the paginator's nextPageUrl method should return null if there is no next page.

Comment: Sorry I was wrong,  I'm used first method not seconds.